# Create a vector dynamically with elements 1 to 6 sequentially in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

In R language, I want to create a vector dynamically during run time. The elements of the vector should be sequentially filled with 1 to 6. for example, if the vector size is 6 means, the elements should be 1,2,3,4,5,6 and if the vector size is 9 means the elements should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. for that, 
I am using the following code

[image]

it works perfectly but when the size was not multiple of 6 means it shows a warning. for this code, I got the required output but it shows a warning. Is there any other method to get the same output without any warning? kindly help to solve this.

[image]

Comment: This is a friendly warning stating that you are doing something wrong., but you can suppress it with `f <- suppressWarnings(matrix(1:6, nrow=1, ncol=9))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a friendly warning that suggest that the dimensions and the data length are not correctly specified, but if we need to suppress it, use the `suppressWarnings()` (not recommended though)

```
f <- suppressWarnings(matrix(1:6, nrow=1, ncol=9))
```

---

Or another option is `length.out` from `rep`

```
f1 <- matrix(rep(1:6, length.out=9), ncol=9)
identical(f, f1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

you can type:

```
seq(x)
```

Example:

```
> seq(6)
# 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

> if the vector size is 6 means, the elements should be 1,2,3,4,5,6 and
>   if the vector size is 9 means the elements should be
>   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

```
v<- matrix(1:9, nrow=1, ncol=9)
f<- matrix(1:6, nrow=1, ncol=6)
```

Comment: For dynamic creation, this method is not suitable